# Flash plugin locks up Firefox, Chrome and Safari behind a corporate proxy, IE6 works fine

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, flash, safari, freeze

At work I am forced by corporate policy to use IE6.

Obviously this is not so good so I use FF for most of my browsing.

However there is a problem once I have installed the Flash plug-in - FF locks up when trying to load Flash media.

Looking at the status bar at the time of the lock up it appears this happens when the browser tries to get cross domain data.

The Flash Active X plug-in in IE does not suffer this issue.

I have tried it in a brand new profile in FF with Flash as the only plug in and it locks up.

We have 2 different proxy servers and both exhibit the same problem.

I have also tried Chrome and Safari and both lock up with the plug-in installed.

So, has anyone else had this problem and solved it?

Or, is there any way to disable cross domain data access in the flash plug-in?

Or, is there any way to disable the "This site needs an additional plug-in" ribbon which appears when the plug-in is not installed.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest [Beta of Chrome](http://www.google.com/landing/chrome/beta/) includes built in support for Flash without the need for the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

> Or, is there any way to disable the
>   "This site needs an additional
>   plug-in" ribbon which appears when the
>   plug-in is not installed.

Firefox add-on [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search?q=flashblock&cat=all&advancedsearch=1&as=1&appid=1&lver=3.6&atype=0&pp=20&pid=5&sort=&lup=) will get rid of the ribbon and replace flash areas with a "play" triangle button. If Flash is not installed, the play button won't work, of course.

Or you can set about:config variable **plugins.hide_infobar_for_missing_plugin** to *true*.

Answer (score 0):

I very much doubt you can change much about the Flash plug-in.

But if IE can use Flash, you could maybe use the [IETab](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419) extension for those sites that need it.

Comment: thanks, but with IETab I may as well just use IE :) The amount of flash out there on the 'net